# Calling local functions in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

js files index.js and utils.js

I have tried to do the module export solution with no luck.

To call a function in utils.js from index.js I write a the function in utils as

```
export.functioname = function(parms) {

...

};
```

If i want to call the same function internally from utils.js i can do it i have to write another identical function as:
var functionname (parms) {
...
}

How can i get around this and only have one function to be called externally and internally?

Comment: sorry it should read exports.functioname

Comment: You can edit your post ;)

Comment: You could just call `exports.functioname(parms)` within the module, as long as you define it before you call it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
var yourfunction = function(param){
    console.log(param);
}

exports.yourfunction = yourfunction;

yourfunction("Works");
```

Which prints:
"Works"

Answer (score 0):

Functions can be saved to variables

```
var moo = function(parms) {}; 

export.functioname = moo;
```

or

```
function moo(parms) {};
export.functioname = moo;
```

works aswell because of js closures